# Changes needed in tomat configuration to avoid JDBC Connection pool exhaustion

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, connection-pool

We occasionaly hit `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolExhaustedException` when threads are holding connections for too long or are going into a deadlock state.

Any recomendation to tweak in Tomcat's DB Connection Configuration or Data source Factory Configuration ?

> 2023-04-16 20:46:20,104  ERROR Exception occurred 36032
> org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolExhaustedException: [https-jsse-nio]
> Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 30 seconds, none
> available [size:200; busy:200; idle:0; lastwait:30000]       .36033 at
> org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:738)

We tried changing `removeAbandoned = true`, `testOnBorrow = true`, `testOnReturn = true` but we still run into the problem. Anything further to check ?

Comment: Do you know what is the longest execution time of your queries? You can set the removeAbandonedTimeout to this time in seconds. Default is 60. Maybe too long?

Comment: Without knowing anything about the type and volume of your Tomcat's workload, it seems like _quite a lot_ to have 200 connections and all of them busy. So, you may be able to manage the issue through pool settings, but tackling the root causes seems like a necessity (obvious comment, I know, and maybe you are already doing that).

Comment: @Mar-Z Longest running query will be within 5 mins. But we would want to identify these bottlenecks. Your suggestion is to set removeAbandonTimeout=60 sec ?

Comment: No. To 5+1=6 sec